# How to use exec in c to run ping multiple times

Tags: c, g++, exec, ping

I am trying to make a simple script to understand how to using the PING command for fun (taking a data security class at uni right now). I have the following code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void )
{
    int status;
    char *args[2];

    args[0] = "ping 192.(hidden for privacy) -s 256 ";        // first arg is the full path to the executable
    args[1] = NULL;             // list of args must be NULL terminated

    if ( fork() == 0 )
        execv( args[0], args );
    else
        wait( &status );       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are three (3) kinds of returns from the function: `fork()`  1) <0 means an error occurred  ==0 means in child process  3) >0 means in the parent process.  The posted code fails to check for the failure condition

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing? Mention the problem's location and description please

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
char *args[2];

args[0] = "ping 192.(hidden for privacy) -s 256 ";        
args[1] = NULL;
```

is not correct, the program `ping` is run by the shell and each string needs to be in a separate argument entry.

Suggest:

```
int main( void )
{
    char *args[] = 
    {
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "ping",
        "190",
        "192...",  // place the IP address here
        "-s",
        "256",
        NULL
    };


    pid_t pid = fork();

    switch( pid )
    {
         case -1:
             // an error occurred
             perror( "fork failed" );
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
             break;

        case 0:
            // in child process
            execv( args[0], args );
            // the exec* functions never return 
            // unless unable to generate 
            // the child process
            perror( "execv failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;

        default:
            int status;
            wait( &status );
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get four errors that say:       desktop.cpp:9:9: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]  "-c", ^.

Comment: Then, I get three errors that say:    desktop.cpp:25:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'perror'
             perror( "fork failed" );
             ^
desktop.cpp:26:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EXIT_FAILURE'
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

Comment: 'perror()` is prototyped in the header file: `stdio.h`.  `exit()' and `EXIT_FAILURE` are prototyped/defined in the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: The comment about: `9:9...` is missing the echo of which actual line is being referred to.  Please post the whole error message

Comment: I got rid of most errors, hoping you can help me figure out the issue with the current build.

Comment: Using the header files you used in the linked code, I changed: `int status; wait( &status );`   to `wait( NULL );`  because of a complaint from the compiler about the variable `status` and the program compiled with no errors.  Your error message seems to be saying that it cannot find the function: `execv()` which is (about) line 33 in the linked code, not line 9  Are you sure your compiling the same code as your posting?